# Why is there an error when grepping man results?

Tags: grep, pipe, man

I am running this command, attempting to grep the output, but I keep receiving this error and I don't understand why.

```
man man | grep color  
<standard input):977: warning [p 8, 0.8i, div '3tbd1,0', 0.0i]: cannot adjust line
```

Any idea what this error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error message generated by `grep`, but by `man`. Run the following to confirm:

```
man man >man.stdout 2>man.stderr
```

And then check `man.stderr`.

This warning indicates a formatting error in the man page for `man` when the output is pure ASCII, not a terminal pager.

Comment: do you know of any way to fix this issue by chance?

Comment: You would have to locate that particular `man.1` source file, check what might be wrong around line 977 and correct it. Otherwise you can safely ignore it, I guess, it's just a warning.